# Mongodb Not connecting in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In Node js using mongodb for saving user chat and users. All the work is done on local. Mongodb work properly but today not connected and return following error.

> { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED'

and my code is

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: Can you connect to Mongodb with terminal?

Comment: `Refused` means, that nobody listen port... Check your mongodb server accessibility

Comment: It seems that you didn't open MongoDB server. Try running `mongod` in your terminal.

Comment: When i'm installing mongodb then return error " mongodb-3.0.1 already installed, it's just not linked " and when  I'm connect mongodb then return this error "-bash: mongod: command not found".

Comment: Mongod return error on terminal "-bash: mongod: command not found".

Comment: As you're just working on local, can you try changing your variable mongoURI just to 'localhost/testing'? Worked for me in local, I believe it may be a connection error to mongodb (maybe loosing credentials in connection?)

Comment: I am trying but not work return error again. warn  - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }

Comment: OK, can you try running sudo service mongodb status to check if mongodb is currently working?

Comment: I am install mongodb " mongodb-3.0.1 " and when I'm starting a service then terminal return "sudo: service: command not found".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mongod server isn't running. The `mongod` command won't  work if your MongoDB installation doesn't have rights outside the core mongo directory. This is common on Windows installations, especially.

Try changing your working directory in your terminal to your Mongo installation directory. On a Windows machine, e.g. `cd C:\Program Files\Mongo` then run `mongod --dbpath (yourAppDBdirectory)`.